# Compiling HHVM - how to add libpthread to linker?

Tags: compiling, 13.04, cmake

I am trying to [compile HipHop VM](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-13.04) on Ubuntu 13.04 and I have this error message:

```
Linking CXX executable gen-ext-hhvm
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../bin/libfolly.a(ExceptionTracerLib.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_once@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'pthread_once@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
```

I've tried to add something like  target_link_libraries({$target} /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0) in CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake but without success.

What and where should I add to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the cmake file:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries({$target} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```